# how to make magic/sysrq across reboot?

Tags: kernel

`sysctl kernel.sysrq=1` makes it work on arch.
but on reboot it goes back again.

i write 1 vlaue to the file `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`
but that is temporary unfortunately.
i am looking for a permanent way.

is there a way, *and not just for this but any command after reboot*.
can i bind reisub to any shortcut key with the help of command line.

any suitable way will be and should be thought out.

how does it all work inside the kernel.
in ubuntu it is enabled by default, how did they manage to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

- Concerning sysrq:
  on Ubuntu there is a file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` which sets up kernel.sysrq. The files there are an extension to the settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.
  I suspect that you can use these files in arch, too. For further information consider the manpages of `man sysctl` and `man sysctl.conf`.
- Concerning arbitrary commands:
  on Ubuntu you can put them e.g. in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`. Search for rc.local support on arch.

Comment: leave sysctl alone. in the file /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq file how to write it permanently "1" for enable, which is a more direct method